# Django email verification link goes to page not found

Tags: django, django-email

I am using conventional email code generation to verify email users. During development when I send the verification link to console and paste in browser it works fine but during production it says page not found.. Have tried all possible option no result.
Kindly check the code below

Validation view

```
def activate(request, uidb64, token):
    try:
        uid = force_text(urlsafe_base64_decode(uidb64))
        user = User.objects.get(pk=uid)
    except(TypeError, ValueError, OverflowError, User.DoesNotExist):
        user = None
    if user is not None and account_activation_token.check_token(user, token):
        user.is_active = True
        user.save()

        messages.success(request, 'Thank you for your email confirmation. Now you can login your account.')
        return redirect('user-login')
```

URL

```
path('activate/(P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/',
         user_views.activate, name='activate'),
```

Email code format
Please click on the link to confirm your registration, http://example.com/activate/(PMTI%5B0-9A-Za-z_%5C-%5D+)/(Pb6ymqe-66b9346a42751b6d94e729b4050698ba%5B0-9A-Za-z%5D%7B1,13%7D-%5B0-9A-Za-z%5D%7B1,20%7D)/

Kindly assist with the issue

Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    https://example.com/activate/(PMTI%5B0-9A-Za-z_%255C-%5D%252b)/(Pb6ymqe-66b9346a42751b6d94e729b4050698ba%5B0-9A-Za-z%5D%257B1,13%257D-%5B0-9A-Za-z%5D%257B1,20%257D)/

activate/(P[0-9A-Za-z_-]+)/(P[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/ [name='activate']
^media/(?P.*)$
The current path, activate/(PMTI[0-9A-Za-z_%5C-]%2b)/(Pb6ymqe-66b9346a42751b6d94e729b4050698ba[0-9A-Za-z]%7B1,13%7D-[0-9A-Za-z]%7B1,20%7D)/, didn’t match any of these.

Comment: replace `path` by `re_path`.

Comment: Still same no changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do it like this, in your `urls.py`:

```
path('activate/<uidb64>/<token>/', user_views.activate, name='activate')
```